# Maven plugin dependency could not be found

Tags: java, maven, wso2, dependency-management

While building my project with maven 3.6.3 using java 1.8 by invoking `maven clean install` I got the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:wso2-esb-proxy-plugin:2.1.0:pom-gen (proxy) on project common: Execution proxy of goal org.wso2.maven:wso2-esb-proxy-plugin:2.1.0:pom-gen failed: Unable to load the mojo 'pom-gen' in the plugin 'org.wso2.maven:wso2-esb-proxy-plugin:2.1.0'. A required class is missing: org/wso2/maven/capp/mojo/AbstractPOMGenMojo`

I learned that a class `org/wso2/maven/capp/mojo/AbstractPOMGenMojo` is included in  `org.wso2.maven/org.wso2.maven.capp/2.1.0/org.wso2.maven.capp-2.1.0.jar`.

My pom fragment looks like:

```
  <parent>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>wso2-esb-proxy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>proxy</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>pom-gen</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactLocation>target/capp/classes</artifactLocation>
              <typeList>${artifact.types}</typeList>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration />
        <!-- here I can enable dependencies to have it working, i.e.
          <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.maven.capp</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
          </dependency>
          ...
        -->
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I found out that after enabling dependencies to plugin (which is put as a comment in above pom's snippet) the code seems to be compiling. I checked that wso2-esb-proxy-plugin-2.1.0.pom in my local maven repo contains:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.maven.capp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Why do I need to put `org.wso2.maven.capp` explicitly as a plugin dependency in pom to have it working? Plugin's pom file already contains the same dependency (although without version) but it seems it's not taken into account in that case.

Comment: Another strange thing is that I have the following warning during the build [WARNING] The POM for org.wso2.maven:wso2-esb-proxy-plugin:jar:2.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available  although the corresponding pom exists in local repository

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to explicitly add dependencies here. It seems the artifact location is wrong in your configurations. Can you change it to following and give it a try?

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>wso2-esb-proxy-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>proxy</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>pom-gen</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactLocation>.</artifactLocation>
        <typeList>${artifact.types}</typeList>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration />
</plugin>
```

This would generate another pom in the location `/target/capp/artifacts/proxy-service/PROXY_NAME` and execute it. Which has the `maven-proxy-plugin` which should download the `org.wso2.maven.capp` dependency.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion but nothing changed. The error is exactly as it had been before. I am wondering what version should be chosen for org.wso2.maven.capp if it's declared in wso2-esb-proxy-plugin-2.1.0.pom without any.

Comment: @Gandalf you can use version 2.1.0.